# Serialise nested list or alternatives

Tags: c#, list, serialization, nested

I am trying to store a collection of lists (each containing over 20.000 int's) and was hoping to use a nested lest for this since each day a new list will be added. 
Eventually I need to access the data in the following way:
"Take the first value of each list and compile a new list". 
Iddeally I'd like to serialise a `List<List<int>>` however this does not seem to work (I can serialise a `List<int>`). Is there a trick to doing this (preferably without getting any addons)?

If not, how would you advice me to store such data efficiently and quick?

The way I try it now:

```
        static void saveFunction(List<int> data, string name)
        {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(name + ".bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
            if (stream.Length == 0)
            {
                List<List<int>> List = new List<List<int>>();
                List.Add(data);
                bin.Serialize(stream, List);
            }
            else
            {
                List<List<int>> List = (List<List<int>>)bin.Deserialize(stream);
                List.Add(data);
                bin.Serialize(stream, List);
            }
        }
        }
```

Strangely the list.Count remains 1, and the number of int in the list remain the same as well while the file size increases.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Each time you serialize...you overwrite existing list. List will always have one element. If you don't serialize a sequence of chunks (one after the other) you have to deserialize older list, add a new element and serialize it again. In general it's terribly slow so you'd better serialize them one after the other (seeking to end). Disadvantage is you have to read them all to get last one (unless you keep some sort of index). If things go more complicate and you have performance requirements then things will become much more complicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rewind the stream and clear the previous data between reading and writing:

```
    static void saveFunction(List<int> data, string name)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(name + ".bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
            if (stream.Length == 0)
            {
                var List = new List<List<int>>();
                List.Add(data);
                bin.Serialize(stream, List);
            }
            else
            {
                var List = (List<List<int>>)bin.Deserialize(stream);
                List.Add(data);
                stream.SetLength(0); // Clear the old data from the file
                bin.Serialize(stream, List);
            }
        }
    }
```

What you are doing now is appending the new list to the end of the file while leaving the old list as-is -- which `BinaryFormatter` will happily read as the (first) object in the file when it is re-opened.

As for your second question, "how would you advice me to store such data efficiently and quick?", since your plan is to "take the first value of each list and compile a new list", it appears you're going to need to re-read the preceding lists when writing a new list.  If that were not true, however, and each new list was independent of the preceding lists, `BinaryFormatter` does support writing multiple root objects to the same file.  See here for details: [Serializing lots of different objects into a single file](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2007/07/serializing-lots-of-different-objects.html)